# Certbot renew failing with connection timeout

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm experiencing an issue while renewing my certificates. When I run the command **certbot renew --dry-run** to renew my two certificates, both fail during verification with the following error:

```
Detail: Fetching
https://www.domainname.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/secretString:
Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
```

Still, if I visit that link I do get a 404 message (not a timeout). Moreover, if I try to visit the original secret file (following the resource name in the above uri, e.g. "https://www.domainname.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/originalSecret") I can correctly retrieve it. I don't understand why certbot cannot establish a connection if I can and if the original creation process worked.

I also tried to reissue a new certificate but still the renewal process fails. I thought it could be that, given that the URI points to a 404 page, certbot could not create the file. However the webroot is the right one, so it should be able to do that with no problem.

Do you have any suggestions?

My configuration is the following: I have nginx running in a container with a volume that maps the certbot webroot to the .well-known folder on the server. Again, it works perfectly for the already existing certificates and for new ones.

Thank you in advance

Comment: if you're self-hosting the site, check that the http URL actually works outside your network. my issue ended up being that my ISP blocks port 80, so certbot always failed. once they opened it, problem solved.